# Failed to install nextcloud android library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, nextcloud

When syncing Gradle, I have the error

> Failed to resolve: com.github.nextcloud:android-library:latest.release

I tried to add JitPack on `build.gradle` (project) but I got

> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project
> repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file
> 'build.gradle'

Here's `build.gradle` (project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}
```

Here's `build.gradle` (module):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.app'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0' // Add this line
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0' // Add this line
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.nextcloud:android-library:latest.release'
}
```

And here's `settings.gradle` where I added Jitpack:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "app"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1):

move 'jitpack' like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
```